# Mouse movement function

Tags: autohotkey

I'm working on a script that focuses on faster mousing. It has hotkeys to:

- snap the cursor to hard-coded locations,
- swap the cursor to the location where it was last swapped from, and
- save and snap to custom locations.

I've been steadily refactoring with an eye to DRY and other principles. For example, the script used to manually define several variables, but now it uses an array. However, I'm coming from a Python background and still getting used to AHK, so the mix between traditional variables vs expressions, commands vs functions, etc. is kind of confusing.

`MoveLocation` used to also send a click if the cursor was within 10 pixels of that saved location, but I ran into some problems:

- The click was being sent while the hotkey modifiers were held down. I bypassed this by checking whether the key was physically held down... sometimes (I'm calling these hotkeys with extra mouse buttons mapped to the various defined hotkeys), which mostly worked, but it would still include <kbd>Control</kbd> while clicking File Explorer in the taskbar with multiple windows open. Thus, instead of popping the row of window previews, it would swap between each window, which is what happens if you <kbd>Control</kbd>-click that. To avoid this, I used...
- The `Sleep` command, which, while solving the problem, also introduced a noticeable delay. It only handled <kbd>Control</kbd> reliably with a delay of 50ms or more, which was bugging me.

Here's the removed code:

```
; if Ctrl isn't physically held down, stop sending it
if GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P") {
    Send {Ctrl Up}
    Sleep, 50
}
MouseGetPos, tempx, tempy
; if the current position is close to the save point, click it
if (Abs(tempx-x)<10 && Abs(tempy-y)<10) {
    MouseMove, x, y
    Click
} ; is clicking a good idea? might be cleaner to remove that logic
; otherwise, move to the save point
else {
```

Removing that made the script more reliable and consistent. It's not much of a hassle to just use the ordinary mouse button to click saved hotspots. However, I now feel that maybe there's some other useful thing I could have the script do if I click the "go to hotspot" hotkey while the cursor is already on it.

The current version of the script that I'm actively practicing with is shown below:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0
SysGet, TotalWidth, 78
SysGet, TotalHeight, 79
SysGet, monitors, MonitorCount
offset := TotalWidth // monitors
start := offset // 2
x1 := start + offset * 0
x2 := start + offset * 1
y := TotalHeight // 2
rx1 := x1
ry1 := y
rx2 := x2
ry1 := y
count := 0
locations := []

Loop 11 {
    locations.Push([0,0])
}

; shift-pause to snap to left monitor, alt-pause to right
+Pause::MouseMove, x1, y
!Pause::MouseMove, x2, y

; swap to last swapped location
Pause::
    if (count) {
        MouseGetPos, rx1, ry1
        MouseMove, rx2, ry2
        count--
    }
    else {
        MouseGetPos, rx2, ry2
        MouseMove, rx1, ry1
        count++
    }
    return

; Ctrl+Shift+NumpadNumber to save a hotspot
; Ctrl+NumpadNumber to go to or click a hotspot

MoveLocation(ID) {
    global locations
    MouseMove, locations[ID][1], locations[ID][2]
}

SaveLocation(ID) {
    MouseGetPos, x, y
    global locations
    locations[ID] := [x, y]
}

^NumpadEnd::SaveLocation(1)
^Numpad1::MoveLocation(1)
^NumpadDown::SaveLocation(2)
^Numpad2::MoveLocation(2)
^NumpadPgDn::SaveLocation(3)
^Numpad3::MoveLocation(3)
^NumpadLeft::SaveLocation(4)
^Numpad4::MoveLocation(4)
^NumpadClear::SaveLocation(5)
^Numpad5::MoveLocation(5)
^NumpadRight::SaveLocation(6)
^Numpad6::MoveLocation(6)
^NumpadHome::SaveLocation(7)
^Numpad7::MoveLocation(7)
^NumpadUp::SaveLocation(8)
^Numpad8::MoveLocation(8)
^NumpadPgUp::SaveLocation(9)
^Numpad9::MoveLocation(9)
^NumpadIns::SaveLocation(10)
^Numpad0::MoveLocation(10)
^NumpadDel::SaveLocation(11)
^NumpadDot::MoveLocation(11)

; mousewheel version for basic mice
~MButton & WheelUp::
    Send {Esc}
    MouseMove, x1, y
    return
~MButton & WheelDown::
    Send {Esc}
    MouseMove, x2, y
    return
```

There's still some code smell from that big block of `SaveLocation`/`MoveLocation` hotkey definitions near the bottom. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out the `Hotkey` command, and using <kbd>Shift</kbd> as a modifier with the number pad requires different key names (e.g. `^NumpadEnd` instead of `^+Numpad1`), so I don't even know if `Hotkey` would work.

I welcome answers related to refactoring or to the actual utility of the script.